# Parsing csv with sed and perl one-liner?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl

I have a web server which stores configurations to PostgreSQL, and I plan to retrieve information from a certain table and then later parse it into csv format.

**PAYLOAD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><rule roleDefinition="false" id="1168" type="COMMON" enabled="true" owner="admin" buildingBlock="false" scope="LOCAL"><name>Recon: Remote Windows Server Scanner</name><notes>Reports a remote host attempting reconnaissance or suspicious connections on common Windows server ports to more than 60 hosts in 10 minutes.</notes><testDefinitions><test uid="4" id="80" name="com.q1labs.semsources.cre.tests.ThresholdFunction_Test" group="Functions"><text>when any of these &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "1")' class='dynamic'&gt;BB:CategoryDefinition: Recon Events, BB:CategoryDefinition: Suspicious Events&lt;/a&gt; with the same &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "2")' class='dynamic'&gt;source IP&lt;/a&gt; more than &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "3")' class='dynamic'&gt;5&lt;/a&gt; times, across &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "4")' class='dynamic'&gt;more than&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "5")' class='dynamic'&gt;59&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "6")' class='dynamic'&gt;destination IP&lt;/a&gt; within &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "7")' class='dynamic'&gt;10&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href='javascript:editParameter("4", "8")' class='dynamic'&gt;minutes&lt;/a&gt;</text>
```

**Steps**

```
perl -nle '
my @enabled = /(?<=enabled="").*?(?<=\"\")/g;
chop(@enabled);
chop(@enabled);
chomp(@enabled);
my @group = /(?<=group="").*?(?<=\"\")/g;
chop(@group);
chop(@group);
chomp(@group);
my @name = /(?<=<name>).*?(?=<\/name>)/g;chomp(@name);
my @text = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;chomp(@text);
print "@enabled;@group;@name;@text"
' Rules.csv |sed 's/\&lt\;/</g'|sed 's/\&gt\;/>/g' | sed -e 's/<*>//g' -e '/ *$/d' > Rules2.csv
```

`Rules2.csv` shows no content, and empty file, however when I break the command I get some very positive results, please see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vCFRP5jq) (as the code) is bit too long. The pastebin analysis would show that somewhere in command section `sed -e 's/<*>//g' -e '/ *$/d'` it results into empty my Rules2.csv file. But I don't know why or what is causing this behavior.

Any help that helps me achieve the desired output as shown in pastebin would be wonderful.

Comment: Exact duplicate to http://superuser.com/questions/699955/parsing-using-one-liner-with-sed-plus-perlerrors

Comment: You're very welcome. Please try to insert a couple of newlines into your XML payload as well if that wouldn't interfere with your intended question. Also, welcome to U&L :)

Comment: @JosephR. Let me do it. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you [should not parse XML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552), this works with your sample input:

```
perl -ple '
    ($enabled) = /(?<=enabled=").*?(?=")/g;
    ($group)   = /(?<=group=").*?(?=")/g;
    ($name)    = /(?<=<name>).*?(?=<\/name>)/g;
    ($text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;
    $_= "$enabled;$group;$name;$text";
    s/&lt;.*?&gt;//g;
' Rules.csv
```

```
true;Functions;Recon: Remote Windows Server Scanner;when any of these BB:CategoryDefinition: Recon Events, BB:CategoryDefinition: Suspicious Events with the same source IP more than 5 times, across more than 59 destination IP within 10 minutes
```

Notes:

- your "enabled" and "group" lookarounds were broken
- if you're working in perl, you don't need to pipe into sed
- <strike>the reason `s/<*>//g` erases all output is that you're matching **zero or more open brackets** up to the last close bracket -- this matches your entire string.</strike>

  - you probably intended `s/<[^>]*>//g`

Comment: thanks for making me realize my error by explicit mentioning them.I will run this code now.